# Polymer 1.0 paper-drawer-panel Not Working in Chrome over CloudFlare

Tags: polymer-1.0

I've been using Polymer 1.0 and am facing a very weird issue. I'm using the standard `paper-drawer-panel` component like this:

```
<paper-drawer-panel id="main-drawer-panel">
    <paper-header-panel drawer id="sidebar" mode="waterfall">
        // content
    </paper-header-panel>

    <paper-header-panel main id="main-container" mode="waterfall">
        <paper-toolbar>
            // content
        </paper-toolbar>
        <div id="content-container> // content .. </div>
    </paper-header-panel>
<paper-drawer-panel>
```

And this works fine in my local computer, and deployed just fine, both in http and https with self-signed certificate. A problem arises when I serve the site through CloudFlare (I use it to [get trusted certificate via the "Full SSL" option](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl)).

Once the site is served through CloudFlare, the `paper-header-panel#main` component got kicked out of `paper-drawer-panel`'s content area, **only in Chrome**.

Here's a screenshot showing the site on Firefox, with CloudFlare's SSL:

[image: Firefox + Cloudflare]

On Chrome without CloudFlare which works fine just like on Firefox (notice the crossed https):

[image: Chrome without CloudFlare]

And finally, on Chrome with CloudFlare:

[image: Chrome + CloudFlare]

I've get the diff on the HTML for both Chrome Before CloudFlare vs Firefox and Chrome After CloudFlare vs Firefox and see no difference. I'm not even sure where to begin debugging on this.

Is there something I am doing wrong? What should I do to get more info about this?

Thanks before.

EDIT: For clarity, the version of Chrome where this is not working is Version 44.0.2403.125 (64-bit) on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Just in case, I'd clean chrome's cache (yeah, it might sound silly... but... you know... just in case)

Comment: @Logain I've clean cache and also run in incognito several times. Still got the same result :/

Comment: this is weird. Did you check what is actually happening with the requests? Are you using cdn for polymer? Some polymer elements weren't working for certain combination of polymer/chrome versions. If you are being served a different version of polymer, strange things might happen.

Comment: @Logain I've added the Chrome version I use. I serve the polymer file through my server (via bower_component), but CloudFlare might change it via their server for CDN purpose. I'll check and report back later.

Comment: @Logain I've tried to turn off the CDN, and still got the same result. I have no idea how to check what's going on with the request between my server and CloudFlare. I'll try to find some way.

Comment: You can check if the polymer version is the right one by running `Polymer.version` on the developer console

Comment: I currently can't edit the question (don't know why), but `Polymer.version` shows 1.0.8 both with and without CloudFlare.